# Error using selenium for web scrapping, how to solve chrome driver error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I had an error when using news fetch to extract news on websites in both french and arabic language.

I am using this github project: https://github.com/santhoshse7en/news-fetch

And when I run

```
google = google_search('Alcoholics Anonymous','https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/')
```

And when I uploaded the last version of chrome driver and dropped the file of 102 version chrome was shut down, I need your help please.

```
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\news-fetch-master\newsfetch\google.py", line 28, in __init__
    driver = get_chrome_web_driver(options)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\news-fetch-master\newsfetch\helpers.py", line 34, in get_chrome_web_driver
    return webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 275, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 103
Current browser version is 102.0.5005.115 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: Your chrome version is slightly ahead downgrade to 102. They should be matching.

Comment: The question needs styling. At first look, it's very hard to understand what is happening.

Comment: error shows that it uses driver which can work only with version 103 but you have installed version 102. You have to upgrade Chrome to version 103 or you have to downgrade driver to version which can work with 102

Comment: your chrome driver and chome broswer version is not compatible